# Test for the presence of the ouya ODK

Tags: java, android, ouya

How would it be possible to test for the presence of the ODK at run time?
Currently I took this approach:

```
private activityDelegate delegate;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Need to test for the presence of the ouya ODK here
    {
        delegate = new OuyaDelegate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

But maybe there is a better way of doing this than in the main activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to pick a class that you know should exist and then see whether it does:

```
try{
    Class.forName("tv.ouya.console.api.OuyaFacade");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    Log.e(TAG, "No ODK Found!");
}
```

Comment: Great that did it!